# Elastic net issue in R - Error in check_dims(x = x, y = y) : nrow(x) == n is not TRUE

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science, r-caret

Error: nrow(x) == n is not TRUE

I am not sure what "n" is referring to in this case. Here is the code throwing the error:

```
# BUILD MODEL 
set.seed(9353)
elastic_net_model <- train(x = predictors, y = y,
                           method = "glmnet",
                           family = "binomial",
                           preProcess = c("scale"),
                           tuneLength = 10,
                           metric = "ROC",
                           # metric = "Spec",
                           trControl = train_control)
```

The main problem that others were running into with this error is that their y variable was not a factor or numeric. They were often passing it as a matrix or dataframe. I explicitly make my y a factor, shown here:

```
# Make sure that the outcome variable is a two-level factor
dfBlocksAll$trophout1 = as.factor(dfBlocksAll$trophout1)

# Set levels for dfBlocksAll$trophout1
levels(dfBlocksAll$trophout1) <- c("NoTrophy", "Trophy")

# Split the data into training and test set, 70/30 split
set.seed(1934)
index <- createDataPartition(y = dfBlocksAll$trophout1, p = 0.70, list = FALSE)
training  <- dfBlocksAll[index, ]
testing <- dfBlocksAll[-index, ]

# This step is the heart of the process
y <- dfBlocksAll$trophout1 # outcome variable - did they get a trophy or not?
predictors <- training[,which(colnames(training) != "trophout1")]
```

The only other potentially relevant code that comes before the block throwing the error is this:

```
train_control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                              number = 10,
                              repeats = 10,
                              # sampling = "down",
                              classProbs = TRUE, 
                              summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                              allowParallel = TRUE,
                              savePredictions = "final",
                              verboseIter = FALSE)
```

Since my y is already a factor, I assume that my error has something to do with the x, not the y. As you can see from the code that my x is a dataframe called "predictors." This dataframe contains 768 obs. of 67 vars, and is filled with chars and numerics.

Comment: You do realize that glmnet cannot handle NA's, right? And why are you not reporting results of `dim` and `summary` (or perhaps with sapply(predictors, function(x){sum(is.na(x))})` on the objects predictors and y?????

Answer (score 0):

Your response variable has to come from the training, here I use an example dataset:

```
dfBlocksAll = data.frame(matrix(runif(1000),ncol=10))
dfBlocksAll$trophout1 = factor(sample(c("NoTrophy", "Trophy"),100,replace=TRUE))

index <- createDataPartition(y = dfBlocksAll$trophout1, p = 0.70, list = FALSE)
training  <- dfBlocksAll[index, ]
testing <- dfBlocksAll[-index, ]
```

And this part should be changed:

```
y <- training$trophout1 
predictors <- training[,which(colnames(training) != "trophout1")]
```

And the rest runs pretty ok:

```
elastic_net_model <- train(x = predictors, y = y,
                           method = "glmnet",
                           family = "binomial",
                           preProcess = c("scale"),
                           tuneLength = 10,
                           metric = "ROC",
                           trControl = train_control)

elastic_net_model
glmnet 

71 samples
10 predictors
 2 classes: 'NoTrophy', 'Trophy' 

Pre-processing: scaled (10) 
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 10 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 65, 64, 64, 63, 64, 64, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  alpha  lambda        ROC        Sens       Spec      
  0.1    0.0003090198  0.5620833  0.5908333  0.51666667
  0.1    0.0007138758  0.5620833  0.5908333  0.51666667
  0.1    0.0016491457  0.5614583  0.5908333  0.51083333
  0.1    0.0038097407  0.5594444  0.5933333  0.51083333
```